# React Navigation passando parâmetros para rota irmão Stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Olá, tenho a seguinte estrutura:

- Workouts

  - index.jsx
  - WorkoutInfo

    - index.jsx
- Home

  - index.jsx
- Profile

  - index.jsx
- Notifications

  - index.jsx

É uma página Home normal e uma página Workouts que mostra todos os treinos, que quando o usuário clica em algum treino mostra a página WorkoutInfo, que mostra informações desse treino. Para fazer isso fiz 2 Rotas, uma Bottom Tabs e outra Stack:

> AppTabs.jsx

```js
const { Navigator, Screen } = createBottomTabNavigator();

const AppTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Navigator>
      <Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Screen name="AllWorkouts" component={WorkoutStack} />
      <Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
    </Navigator>
  );
}

export default AppTabs;
```

> WorkoutStack.jsx

```js
const { Navigator, Screen } = createStackNavigator();

const WorkoutStack = () => {
  return (
    <Navigator>
      <Screen name="AllWorkouts" component={Workouts} />
      <Screen name="WorkoutInfo" component={WorkoutInfo} />
    </Navigator>
  );
}

export default WorkoutStack;
```

Dentro do `Workouts/index.jsx` só fiz um `onPress={() => navigate('WorkoutInfo', { workoutId: id })}`, nada demais.

Qual o problema?

Dentro da minha Home, tem uma área em que alguns treinos são mostrados, somente alguns, e o usuário pode clicar e deveria ir para a mesma página "WorkoutInfo". Então escrevi idêntico ao que escrevi no `Workouts/index.jsx`,  `onPress{() => navigate('WorkoutInfo', { workoutId: id })` porém quando clico no treino, recebo um erro dizendo:

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name": "WorkoutInfo", "params": { workoutId: 6 }} was not handled by any navigator.

> Do you have a screen named "WorkoutInfo"??

E eu simplesmente não sei o que estou fazendo de errado.
Se alguém puder me dar uma luz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *Navigators* aninhados não recebem eventos de seus pais

Dada a seguinte estrutura:

```
Home (Home)
AllWorkouts (WorkoutStack)
    AllWorkouts (Workouts)
    WorkoutInfo (WorkoutInfo)
Profile (Profile)
Notifications (Notifications)
```

Têm-se dois níveis de navegação: a principal (`Home`, `AllWorkouts`, `Profile` e `Notifications`) e uma interna de `AllWorkouts` (`AllWorkouts` e `WorkoutInfo`).

Quando você está numa tela interna (e.g. `WorkoutInfo`) e utiliza `navigation.navigate`, um evento é emitido para ser recebido por algum `Navigator`, podendo ser tanto o mais interno (`WorkoutStack`) quanto o mais externo (`AppTabs`). O contrário não é verdade, por isso não é possível navegar de `Home` para `WorkoutInfo` do jeito que está na pergunta e surge o erro *was not handled by any navigator*.

---

### Navegando para uma tela em um *navigator aninhado*

Para resolver o problema, duas coisas devem ser feitas:

1. Parar de usar nomes duplicados (existem dois `AllWorkouts`) - isso não causará problemas diretamente, porém deixa o código mais confuso.
2. Navegar de `Home` para o Navigator `AllWorkouts`, indicando qual a tela desejada e passando o parâmetro que essa tela precisa:

```js
navigation.navigate('AllWorkouts', {
  screen: 'WorkoutInfo',
  params: { workoutId: id }
});
```

Para mais detalhes sobre *navigators aninhados*, leia toda a página da documentação [Nesting navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/), lá existem exemplos de diversas situações que provavelmente lhe serão úteis.

Comment: Você salvou minha vida cara, valeu mesmo!